# How to delete logs from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was just playing around with `Cloud Functions` on `Firebase` and deployed some random functions to test it out. Now I want to delete all `logs` on `Firebase console` but I was not able to find a way for that. Is there any `CLI` command to do that or is it going to be there for ever or they will be automatically deleted as they age?

Comment: Just curious why would you want to ? I don't know the answer though.

Comment: There's currently no way to delete logs from the Firebase Console.

Comment: There is currently a feature request out for this.  You can add you voice by filing a feature request of your own.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @TheeBen the same reason you may want to delete or archive read emails in your inbox.

Comment: during development, deleting irrelevant logs is very important. another reason i do not like firebase/gcp too much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cloud Functions log retention is based on the [standard Stackdriver limits](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing). For free projects, logs are kept for 7 days. If you upgrade your stackdriver plan it's 30 days.

You can use [Stackdriver's deletion api](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/delete) to delete the log entries.  The log name for cloud functions should look similar to: `projects/<project-id>/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"` and can be found using the [list api](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/list)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I had the same problem. One more thing, it seems that errors are not being deleted, only info logs. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

That's just an addition to @Kiana answer.

You can see it directly within the `Firebase` console. When trying to choose the timestamp for the logs, logs older than 1 month are disabled, which means are automatically deleted. At least for project's owner, maybe Google stores it somewhere deeper in their logs.

Still, there's no option to delete the logs manually.

**Edit:** maybe it's good to add, but even if you'll delete your function, the logs of the deleted function still will be there for 1 month.

[image: Firebase console]